# Measure server bandwidth

Tags: python, bandwidth, udp

I want to measure a bandwidth of my implemented in Python remailer server, which means I want to measure how many bytes my server is processing per second. So how I was planing to do that is: for a fixed period of time (for example `300sec`), I'm measuring the number of `received bytes` and `sent bytes`. After this period of time I compute the ratio: `bytes_received / bytes_sent`. However, I'm not sure this is what I want, because it gives me a ratio (which usually is around 1-1.5), so this means that I process all or almost all messages which I received in some period of time, but I want to measure how many bytes I processed. I will be very grateful if someone can advice me how I can measure my bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to do this :

**bytes_received** = bytes_received300s - bytes_received0s

**bytes_sent** = bytes_sent300s - bytes_sent0s

**total_bytes_processed** = bytes_received - bytes_sent

This would give you the total number of bytes processed during the 300s period.

Comment: What you mean by bytes_received0s?

Answer (score 0):

You can use psutil.net_io_counters() to calculate the bandwidth over a period of time. You'll take a snapshot at 0 seconds and a snapshot at 300 seconds.

```
def get_bandwidth():
    # Get net in/out
    net1_out = psutil.net_io_counters().bytes_sent
    net1_in = psutil.net_io_counters().bytes_recv

    time.sleep(300) # Not best way to handle getting a value 300 seconds later

    # Get new net in/out
    net2_out = psutil.net_io_counters().bytes_sent
    net2_in = psutil.net_io_counters().bytes_recv

    # Compare and get current speed
    if net1_in > net2_in:
        current_in = 0
    else:
        current_in = net2_in - net1_in

    if net1_out > net2_out:
        current_out = 0
    else:
        current_out = net2_out - net1_out

    network = {"traffic_in": current_in, "traffic_out": current_out}

    # Return data in bytes
    return network
```